# add bundle products items qty to cart programatically Magento

Tags: magento, bundle, product, cart, items

HI i need to add a bundle product with its items qty to cart programaticaaly. For this i am using the below code

```
                $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
                $cart->init();

                $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
                $productId =  3801 ;//3857;

                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);

                if($product->getTypeId() == "bundle"){

                $bundled_items = array();
                $optionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsCollection();
                $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds());
                $options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);
                $childsku = array('testing','staging');

                foreach($options as $option) {
                    $_selections = $option->getSelections();
                    foreach($_selections as $selection) {
                        //print_r($selection);


                        $bundled_items[$option->getOptionId()][] = $selection->getSelectionId();
                        $bundled_qty[$selection->getSelectionId()][] = 2;
                     }
                }
print_r($bundled_items);
print_r($bundled_qty);
                $params = array('bundle_option' => $bundled_items,
                                 'bundle_option_qty'=>$bundled_qty, 
                                'qty' => 1,'product'=>$productId);
                }

                if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                    );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
                }

                $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
                $product->load($productId);

                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                $cart->save();

                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
```

this code add the product to cart properly with all its items i

> need to sprcify the each option qty
>
> but it sets all options qty to 1

.
can you please suggest me where i am doing the mistake or what i should try.

thanks

Comment: Can you give more detail and examples about what you are trying to achieve? For example how many items are in the bundle? Do you always add the same quantity of each item into the bundle or are the quantities passed in via url query parameters (`$params` in your code above). Are the bundled items configurable products, simple products or both? And if the bundle's items are configurable, where are the configured options set (eg size)? Do you only deal with one specific bundle or do you need code to work with any bundle? Do you also need this code to work for other product types or only bundle?

Answer (score 0):

ok i have fix the issue by doing some changes in the script

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
                                $cart->init();
                                $bundled_items = array();
                                $optionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsCollection();
                                $selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getSelectionsCollection($_product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds());
                                $options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);
                                foreach($options as $option) {
                                    $_selections = $option->getSelections();
                                    foreach($_selections as $selection) {
                                        foreach($cusarray as $cusarraykey=> $cusarrayvalue) {
                                            if($selection->getSku()== $cusarrayvalue){
                                                print_r($selection->getSku());
                                                echo $selection->getSku()."<br/>";
                                                $bundled_items[$option->getOptionId()][] = $selection->getSelectionId();
                                                $bundled_qty[$option->getOptionId()] = $cusqtyarray[$cusarraykey];
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                $params = array('bundle_option' => $bundled_items,
                                                 'bundle_option_qty' => $bundled_qty,
                                                'qty' => $proqty,'product'=>$_productId);

                                if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                                        $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                                            array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                                            );
                                        $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
                                }
                                $_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
                                $_product->load($_productId);
                                $cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                                $cart->save();
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

"$bundled_qty[$option->getOptionId()] = $cusqtyarray[$cusarraykey];"
is this how you fixed.